# How to load images from local machine for image classification by Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I know how to load images from local machine for training in tensorflow. I want a way to load images for testing purpose specially when I have used tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator for training.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to load and process images by using `tf.data`.

You may want to have a look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images.

This page also explains the downsides of using `ImageDataGenerator` instead of `tf.data`.